# How do I debug unexpected behaviour with Bootstrap framework?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have added [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to my staging site, built using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/).

Something is going wrong with my Bootstrap responsive menu. The code seems to be fine:

```
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-nav navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
       <div className="container" id="nav">
         <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/"><StaticImage src="../img/logo-min.png" alt="WaJK Logo" height={75}/>
             <span className="we">We </span><span className="are">are </span><span className="just">Just </span><span className="kids">Kids</span>
         </Link>
         <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
           <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
           {
           data.allMdx.nodes.map((node, i) => (
            <li className="nav-item" key={node.frontmatter.url}>
              <Link className="nav-link" to={"../" + node.frontmatter.url}>{node.frontmatter.menu_name}</Link>
            </li>
          ))
          }
          </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </nav>
  )
```

And the scripts are loading okay:

[image]

The `button` correctly appears, and the `navbarResponsive` disappears, on a small screen. But when I click on my `button`, the `navbarResponsive` does not appear - nothing happens when the button is clicked.

How do I debug this to find out what is going wrong? I'm not getting much useful information from Firefox developer tools.

Comment: *"How do I debug this"* is open to interpretation. Since nothing happens when your button is clicked, perhaps show the html and javascript for this button since you want help here? We are unable to log into your computer unless you remove the firewall and give us your IP address. ... So posting your code solves this for security purposes.

Comment: Hi there - thanks. The idea was to give ideas to allow me to solve the problem myself. But the code is available on the "staging site" link above.

Comment: Well links to code (you control) are not in SO rules for asking questions. Think about it, you can delete, modify that code at will. How would that give your question (and the SO community's comments / answers) historical value? ... So the basic idea is for you to post your code on THIS site.

Comment: I was being sarcastic about IP address, but if you dont want to follow the rules I cant help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining the rule which I wasn't aware of (and for doing so so politely). I have updated the question now with code.

Comment: I don't know right away on to solve this per your code. I will +1 you though in hopes to attract someone who knows.